# Data in Database not reflected by Rails calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, best-in-place

This is the strangest bug I've ever encountered

I am using the Best In Place gem in my Rails app in order to allow in-place editing of a page title. The in-place editing works, and the new title gets changed in the database, but when I refresh the page, it reverts back to the old title. I don't even understand where it's getting the old title from, since it's not stored in the database anymore.

When the page is created, it is automatically given the title "Untitled Page". When I change the title to say, "Title", and look at the row for the page in the DB with the postgresql admin program, it does indeed change to "Title". But when I run Page.find(1).title in the rails console, it returns "Untitled Page"

How could this be?!

Comment: Could there be a pooled connection with an open transaction that didn't get properly closed? That way it'd still see old data. Check `pg_stat_activity` while you're testing, see if there are any `<IDLE> in transaction` entries. Also test in `psql` to verify that the data really is changed in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The reason was that I was using after_initialize to set the automatic properties, which gets called whenever the ActiveRecord object gets initialized. What I really wanted was after_create. I use after_create to call a function called set_properties, where I set things like self.title, and then at the end of the function, I call self.save, which is required for the properties to get saved into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app running in production mode?

The PG response and console response cannot be different unless they are being executed on two different databases.

1. Check that your database config is using the same database as the one you are manually connecting to when browsing PG.
2. Ensure that when you run the rails console you specify the environment (in case your default is not what you are running on):
   $ rails c production
   $ rails c development
3. If both of the above don't help, please post the log snippet of this action. Might be that the transaction is being rolled back. If you are using .save or .update_attribute without the "!" then this won't throw an error. This is highly unlikely though, since you are saying that the database has updated data.